# react-redux refreshes the store value when web-page refreshes in react-reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react-redux,when I refresh the webpage state in the reducer are gone.Is this an issue with my code or reducer in react works like that and is there any other way to retain states when we refresh the page.

Comment: react is for Single Page Applications (SPA) which doesn't persist states. That is the expected behavior. If your need to persist state is small, you can use the [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Get the value for the init state from the local storage. Really depends on you though. If everything persists on refresh then I don't think that's an SPA anymore.

Comment: I believe that is how redux behaves. I have found out that you can try redux-persist to help you with this. [Redux Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) takes your Redux state object and saves it to persisted storage. Then on app launch it retrieves this persisted state and saves it back to redux. Need you also know that Redux persist uses your browsers localstorage.

I doubt there is any issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. in react your store clear after refresh page.
when you open project in your browser, your can changing route with `history.push` and store will not be lost in this case.

localStorage and sessionStorage is the best way for keeping the data.

you can set anything in your localStorage and use your data in component constructor for initial state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    products: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('all-products')) || []
  }
}
```

and when you want set products with some changes, you can use callback state as second parameter:

```
this.setState({products: someChangesInProductsList}, state => {
  localStorage.setItem('all-products', JSON.stringify(state.products))
})
```

Also, you can send data to next route with `history.push` like below:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/test',
    state: data
})
```

And get data in componentDidMount in next route with `this.props.history.location.state`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Redux works in this way.

Whenever web page reloads the cache gets cleared and the redux state too.

Data persisting can  be done by :-

1. [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) :- will last till the cache is not cleared
2. [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):- will last till session exists.
3. You can also use [redux persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for persisting your redux state

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redux works this way, when you refresh the page, the state is gone
if you want some data to be persited, you can use local storage or session storage